# Find coordinates where slopes are 0 of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How would I do that with the following equation of the ellipse?

$ x^2-xy+y^2=3$

After Implicit Differentiation:
$ dy/dx = (-2x+y)/(-x+2y)$

Comment: Hint: Differentiate. We get $2x-x\frac{dy}{dx}-y+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.

Comment: Yeah I found what dy/dx equals (I'll update the post), but how do I set dy/dx equal to 0 if I have two variables (x and y)

Comment: Ser it equal to $0$. We  get $2x-y=0$. So $y=2x$. Substitute in the equation of the ellipse and solve.

Comment: Wait did I do my implicit wrong because I got -2x+y and you got the opposite.

Comment: There is no mistake. Note that I didn't bother to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, I set $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ when the equation was in flat form. Fractions are trouble.